# Swift - add up values of struct array

Tags: ios, swift

My intention is to add up all inputs of a value of a struct array. I've done it before, but with a normal array: `let total = array.reduce(0, +)`.

Let's say this is my struct:

```
struct addDataStruct: Codable {
    var driven: Int
    var date: Date
    var consumedL: Double
    var pricePerLiter: Double
}
```

This is my array:

```
var addDataArray: [addDataStruct] = []

func createStructArray() {
        let addData: addDataStruct = addDataStruct(driven: ..., date: Date(), consumedL: ..., pricePerLiter: ...)
        addDataArray.append(addData)
    }
```

**How am I able to add up all values of driven?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let total = array.lazy.map{ $0.driven }.reduce(0, +)
```

OR

```
let total = array.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.driven })
```

Comment: Skip the intermediate array generation. You don't need it :) `let total = array.lazy.map{ $0.driven }.reduce(0, +)`

Comment: Or `array.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.driven }`

Comment: @Alexander i agree this is performance wise

Comment: @MartinR yes it another short way